# Delete duplicated of status for same serial number

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the below table and need to delete the duplicated serial numbers which have different statuse?!!
[image]

Comment: which database you are using for this?

Comment: access 2016 ,thanks

Comment: Delete duplicate serial numbers... *only* the ones with different statuses? Like you want to keep the duplicate serial numbers with the *same* status? Do you care which is older or newer?

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using. Also: It is always better to include your sample data as `formatted text` rather than images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
delete from table1 where [s/n] IN (
    select [s/n] FROM Table1
    group by [s/n]
    having count(Distinct status ) > 1
);
```